# In HTML/CSS, how to use an image as the header at the very top of the page above my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic page that should look like Figure 1 in this link: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements

The only thing is, instead of text for the heading, I want to place an image. I am trying to style the image in CSS to size and center it.

Right under the heading I have an ul which is my navigation bar. Then I have the context which will be a couple paragraphs. Lastly I have the footer.

My problem is, when I try to style the header, I end up having to use "background-image" and the header goes behind the navigation bar rather than the very top of the page.

HTML BODY Example:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="nav">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

</body>
```

What do I have to type in CSS for the header as an image?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS image placement</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #headline1 {
            background-image: url(images/newsletter_headline1.gif);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left top;
            padding-top: 68px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
        #headline2 {
            background-image: url(im`enter code here`ages/newsletter_headline2.gif);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left top;
            padding-top: 68px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headline1">Some text … </div>
        <div id="headline2">Some more text .. </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not recommended to use background image for headers.use embed image using img src and add css to display it as block

Answer (score 1):

Just make a block-level image:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="mypic.png" />
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```